# Print a linked list in C

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, variadic

I am working to develop a linked list API for a Lisp compiler, but I chose to write this part in C because writing it in assembly wouldn't be very fun. I can successfully make a linked list from a series of elements with the `list` function below. I have verified that it works, shown by the examples in `main` below. But why does my function `print_list` only print the first element, and then zero? I am so confused. Please offer any help if you understand what is going wrong.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

typedef struct Node Node;
struct Node {
    int head; // make to a union later
    Node* tail;
};

//////////
Node cons(int curr, Node* next) {Node cell = {curr, next}; return cell;}
int car(Node node) {return node.head;}
Node* cdr(Node node) {return node.tail;}
//////////
void print_elems(Node node) {
    printf("%d", node.head);
    if (node.tail == NULL) return;
    printf(" ");
    print_elems(*node.tail);
}

void print_list(Node node) {
    printf("(");
    print_elems(node);
    printf(")\n");
}
//////////
Node make_pairs(va_list args, int argc) {
    Node linked_list;
    linked_list.head = va_arg(args, int);
    if (argc == 0) {
        linked_list.tail = NULL;
        return linked_list;
    }
    Node tail = make_pairs(args, argc - 1);
    linked_list.tail = &tail;
    return linked_list;
}

Node list(int length, ...) {
    va_list elems;
    va_start(elems, length);
    Node linked_list = make_pairs(elems, length);
    va_end(elems);
    return linked_list;
}
//////////

int main() {
    Node big_list = list(5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5);

    /*
    This is NULL, as expected:
    big_list.tail -> tail -> tail -> tail -> tail -> head

    And this is 1:
    big_list.head
    */

    // but why does this only print "(1 0)"?
    print_list(big_list);
}
```

Comment: `linked_list.tail = &tail;` you are creating a pointer to a *local*  variable. After the function ends this pointer becomes dangling, so your code has *undefined behavior*  when trying to read this pointer

Comment: @UnholySheep Got it, that fixed it thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could print linked list in this kind of manner : **this is an exemple**;
My objective is just to make you notice with pointer you don't have problems with local variable

```
typedef struct Node Node;
Node* first_element = create_list; // just for understanding "first element" is the linked list
Node* ptr = first_element; // copy in another pointer your list then you will avoid loosing your first element and breaking your list (personnal advice : not needed)

while  (ptr->tail){
    ptrinf("%d\n", ptr->head); // for exemple
    ptr = ptr->tail;
} 

//after the while ptr = the last element because ptr->tail == NULL
```

formated to function it looks like that :

```
#include <stdio.h>
typedef struct Node Node;

void display_list (Node* first_element)
{
        Node* ptr = first_element; // copy in another pointer your list then you will avoid loosing your first element and breaking your list (personnal advice : not needed)

        while  (ptr->tail){
            ptrinf("%d\n", ptr->head); // for exemple
            ptr = ptr->tail;
        }

        //after the while ptr = the last element because ptr->tail == NULL
}
```

if i didn't answer the question well tell me, i'm new on stack i would improve ^^.

I hope i helped you.